# How to check the button's text is changed after a click operation on the button

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

Scenario: Check whether the text is changed to "Remove" from "Add to Cart" on the button after the click operation.

I am unable to get the text of the button after click operation is performed. I am getting Stale Element Exception when I try to retrieve the text of the button.

```
btnCart.click();
boolean bNameChange=btnCart.getText().equals("Remove");
if(bNameChnage==true)
{
perform other operations
}
```

b
But Stale Reference Exception is thrown.
I tried WebDriverWait before checking the text value.This throws TimeOutException.

WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(10));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(btnCart, "Remove")));

How to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Thats because once You have clicked on the button , it becomes stale i.e. means an old element or no longer available element

You should do a driver.findElement(locator) again to get the fresh Element and then do a getText()

```
When an element is no longer attached to the DOM, i.e. it has been removed from the document or the document has changed, it is said to be stale. Staleness occurs for example when you have a web element reference and the document it was retrieved from navigates.
```

You can read more below
[StaleElementReference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver/Errors/StaleElementReference)

Comment: Thank you. I am using PageFactory for intializing the web elements. So should I call PageFactory.initElements() function after button click??

Comment: @Subha This is a known problem with the PageFactory implementation, I would suggest defining a By Object for the element locator and to Find the locator again using driver.findElement(by), probably you can write a try catch block to do that